# Rewrite results "read more" link death

Tags: 7, nodes

**My rewrite result settings:**
[image]

**My general settings:**
[image]

the "read more" link from the teaser doesn't redirect me to the article, When pressed, it redirects me to the main page (current one).

When leaving the "more link path" empty, it should redirect me to the blogpost (article).

Some values I've tried for "link more path":

```
[path]
[node/id]
[node:title]
[title]
```

Is this not working because I also got the "URL aliases" module installed? Which cleans my url like this:

```
www.mysite.com/blog/awesome-article-about-ducks
```

instead of this:

```
www.mysite.com/blog/node/41
```

Comment: you can add an nid field and exclude that from the display. Keep that above the body field so that you can get the same as in the body field.

then give the path as /node/[nid]

Comment: @MohammedShameem I can't follow you, it is not an individual link. I've set the rewrite results along with the body.

Comment: @MohammedShameem's idea is correct. Add a node nid field and rearrange the fields so it is above the field with the more link. Exclude it from display. Then in the field with the more link you can use its value in your link path setting, via the token [nid].

Comment: @duck : Can you check what the read more's href tag has using the inspect element?

Comment: @Gladiator <a href="/mysite/blog/drupal/" class="views-more-link" data-thmr="thmr_11">Read more</a>   Generated by Drupal itself

Comment: @duck : Try the below answer, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this.,

Step :1

> 1. Add the nid to the views and exclude it from the display.
> 2. Place this nid before all fields in the views. Only by placing it above the all fields, we can get this as a token in the replacement.
> 3. Now use node/[nid] as the path to link.
> 4. This will worl

Step : 2

> 1. Add content:link as a field.
> 2. Add set the nid in the replacement pattern.

Difference between the 2.

> Step:1 shows the read more only when the length is greater than the
>   trim value. Else it will not show.
>
> Step:2 will show the read more in all the cases. Even the body is
>   empty it will show read more, but this will not happen in step 1.

Comment: Step 1 did it for me, works like a charm mister! Wish I could vote your answer!

Comment: Nice to know that I could help you, but it was @MohammedShameem 's idea that made me to write this answer. Equal credit goes to him too.

Comment: Good to know that it helped....